# Jenkins setup for multiple tasks

Tags: svn, unix, jenkins

I am setting jenkins project on *nix system that has following flow .

1. take checkout from branches from SVN
2. compile above code checkout from svn using ANT
3. create DSL
4. select dsl and environment server ip ,port
5. push DSL to selected environment (ip,port)

Do I have to create all these as a single job and then clubbed together in project.
Shall I use pipeline or multijob plugins for this? It would be better if I can also independently start any of these steps at any point of time like just "checkout and compile" to see if build is stable or not.these steps are mostly sequentially but not always.
could you please help me how to manage this workflow in jenkins easily ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Jenkins will watch your Subversion repository and fire the job off as soon as it detects someone make a commit on that particular Subversion URL. It will also handle the checkout and/or update, so that's Step #1 already handled.

In the *build* step, Jenkins can do multiple build steps including compiling with Ant (is this a Java project? If not, why are you using Ant?). Run other builds and shell scripts, and then examine the exit status of each of these and pronounce the build as a success or failure. That can take care of steps 2 - 5 for you.

Of course, there are various plugins that can be used to FTP files, run post-build shell scripts, etc. For example, if you have a location where compiled code (like Java JAR files are fetched from), you can do this in a post-build step.

The advantage of a post-build step is that it can handle things that you may not have in your Ant build file, (such as the FTP step or tagging the build). Post-build steps can generate charts graphs from unit tests, coding style plugins like Findbugs, Checkstyle, JavaDoc generation, PMD, etc.

The problem with build and post-build steps is that if any one fails, your build is marked as a failure. This may not be what you want.

In that case, you can divide your *build* up into several components. For example, one component compiles and builds the DSL. The other *pushes* the DSL to the environment. This way, your *build* could succeed, but the second job triggered by our build -- pushing the DSL into the environment -- can be marked as a separate failure.

You can also use the Promotion Plugin too. This plugin has the advantage of letting you select particular builds. For example, the pushing the DSL to the environment could be a Promotion step. When you find a build you like, you *promote* the DSL push to the environment. We use Ant with Ivy and Maven to produce jars. I use the Promotion Plugin for two things. When a build successfully completes, I publish that jar as a SNAPSHOT via a Promotion Plugin job that fires whenever a build is successful. When a developer is happy with a jar, he manually promotes it with another Promotion Plugin job that will publish the jar into our RELEASE repository that all other projects will use.

Basically, there is no *right answer* with using Jenkins. You can put all of your steps into a single build process (which can run dozens of build systems), or divide the build up into multiple builds that get triggered one after another. (You can use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to copy something built in one build into another.) Or, you can use the Promotion Plugin to let you select which builds you want to push into your environment.

Fortunately, Jenkins is easy to setup and use, and you'll fairly quickly get the hang of it. You can try things one way, then try it another way and see which way works the best.

Comment: I haven't used the pipeline plugin, but it sounds like you may find it useful. Looking at the documentation, it doesn't look like it actually does much to build the pipeline - just display the entire pipeline in a single screen. It says you need to trigger other builds as part of a _post-build-action_ (standard Jenkins configuration). And, you still probably need the Copy Artifacts Plugin I mentioned above. So, three builds, copy the artifacts from one to another, and trigger the next build as part of the post build _Projects to Build_.

Comment: Thanks a lot David for such a clear answer.Could you please help me how to break my process into components.I would like to break it in 3 components.Component 1(Step 1 ,2 : Checkout and compile), component 2(Step3 only DSL creation) ,component 3(step 4,5) .Shall I use pipeline plugin or any other plugin ?ANd how should I select my environment IP and port ? Kindly suggest

Comment: Ok David.What about selection of environment IP and port ? I couldnt understand your last line ""So, three builds, copy the artifacts from one to another, and trigger the next build as part of the post build Projects to Build"" Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Do you need to manually enter in the IP and port? Or, are those the same per build? Or, are there multiple IP and ports? You may need to use the Promotion Plugin, so you can specify these items, and not automatically do a deployment each time. There's a special [Build With Parameters](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+With+Parameters+Plugin) plugin that you may find useful. I used that once a long time ago. It lets you do a _standard_ build that's automatically triggered, but trigger a special build with special parameters.

Comment: You have BUILD_A that does your compile. You have BUILD_A trigger BUILD_B that builds your DSL. To do BUILD_B, you need to copy the compiled artifacts from BUILD_A to BUILD_B, so BUILD_B can build the DSL. BUILD_B will trigger BUILD_C (and again copy the DSL or whatever is needed) to deploy with a standard port and ip to a server. BUILD_C can use the Build w/ Parameters plugin, so someone can trigger another build to a different Port and IP. Or, you may want to have a _Build Promotion_ as part of BUILD_B (and forget BUILD_C) to select the port and IP and do the deployment. Either way will work

Comment: Ok David.... Here, we have multiple IP and ports and need to enter manually...(right now we are using shell script to deploy by reading these environment from a text file),,After entering these environment IP ,port ,these will be used in POST BUILD step to perform some additional tasks(replacing tokens,files based on ip,port),How can I pass env port selected by JOB user to be passed later on as variable in post build step??

Comment: @JazzR The first project compiles and builds the DSL (building the DSL could be a second project if desired). The entering of the IPs and Ports, and the deployment is a separate project. This can use the [Parameterized Build Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build). When you ***manually*** trigger this deployment project, it will ask you for the port and IP addresses. You can also use the [Copy Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to give this deployment Jenkins job whatever it needs in order to do the deployment.

Comment: Thanks David for your help . It was nice tutorial for me .